# Minimize Function working online but not on desktop

Tags: mathematical-optimization, warning-messages

```
Minimize[((2 p + 1)*Log [2] + (2 p)*Log [p] + (2 - 2 p)*
 Log [(1 - p)])*(-(2 p)*Log[p] - (1 - 2 p)*Log[(0.5 - p)])^-1, p]
```

This function is working online but showing error in desktop Mathematica, what could be the issue?

Comment: "showing error in software" - mentioning the text of the error messages you're getting would help a great deal.

Comment: Thank you so much @ J.M.

Answer (score 1):

Errors are pretty self explanatory:

> NMinimize::nrnum: The function value -0.115134-0.525861 I is not a real number at {p} = {0.934341}.

So give it appropriate domain:

```
Minimize[
  { ((2 p + 1)*Log[2] + (2 p)*Log[p] + (2 - 2 p)*Log[(1 - p)])*(-(2 p)*Log[p] - (1 - 2 p)*Log[(0.5 - p)])^-1
  , 0 < p < .5
  }
, p
]
```

> ```
> {-0.0893733, {p -> 0.350457}}
> ```